# Elements starts bugging with float: left

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the searchbox turns into a big box instead of a thin rectangle. Also the navigation bar jumps down very weirdly. I want everything aligned horizontally.

If I remove the searchbox everything works just fine; the navigation bar jumps up to where it should be.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <section id="headerContainer">
        <a href="/"><section id="logo">HALP A DOG</section></a>
      <section id="searchBox">Searchbox</div>
        <nav>
         <ul>
         <a href="/"><li><div class="articles_icon"></div>DOGS</li></a>
         <a href="products.php"><li><div class="farms_icon"></div>LEACH</li></a>
         <a href="motivation.php"><li><div class="buy_icon"></div>WATER</li></a>
         <a href="#"><li id="sell"><div class="sell_icon"></div>ABOUT</li></a>
         </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
  </header>
```

**CSS**

```
 header{
    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #F66000;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px black;
}

section#headerContainer{
    border: 1px solid black;
}

section#logo{
    padding-top: 23px;
    padding-left: 1.5%;
    font-size: 50px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 68px;
    float: left;
    font-family: via;
}

section#searchBox {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 6%;
  float: left;
  width: 12%;
  height: 1.5%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

nav{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  margin-left: 20%;

 nav ul li{
border-left: 2px solid black;
width: 120px;
height: 90px;
position: relative;
float: left;
text-align: center;
background: #171717;
color: #F66000;
font-weight: bold;
```

} 
    }

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Unordered list items <li> cannot be wrapped in other elements. The A tags go INSIDE, not outside.

Comment: I have to have the A tag outside the <li> because I want the whole box to be clickable, not only the text. I don't understand how this could be a problem. As mentioned, if I remove the searchbox everything works very good. :)

Comment: Your code is invalid and does not work. What is there to not understand?

Comment: They are correct, you can't put a block level element inside an inline element, it's invalid code. If you want the entire `li` to be clickable, just set the anchor inside the `li` to `display:block;`

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid:

```
<a href="/"><li><div class="articles_icon"></div>DOGS</li></a>
```

Should be:

```
<li><a href="/"><div class="articles_icon"></div>DOGS</a></li>
```

On top of that, you should be using `display:block` on your A-tag and applying the CSS background to the A-tag. The DIV is redundant and there's no reason to use it. You should be using `float:left` on the LI, not the NAV itself.

```
nav a {
    display:block;
    background-image:url(...);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```